# Replacing Special Characters in a CSV file

Tags: c#, ssis

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785805/hyphen-vs-dash-replace-dash-with-hyphen) StackOverflow article, I realized that I was having the same issue with my CSV file, namely, where someone copy and pasted a dash/hypen (-) character from Word into an Excel.

I was creating my own CSV file with data read from an Excel spreadsheet and I was noticing strange characters like â€ appearing in Excel that did not appear when viewing in Notepad. When I used SSIS to transfer the CSV file to a SQL Server table, the weird â€ persisted there too. After examining the ASC value of each, I decided to replace ASC 150 (Dash) with and ASC 45 (hyphen) character and this corrected the problem and the hypen appeared normal when viewing in in Excel also.

This led me to question what other characters might also need to be replaced and if there was a general routine that could be employed to safeguard my CSV file from having similar issues.

This is what I am currently doing for every value that I want to write to a CSV file. Note that my getCharacterString function is similar to VB's CHR function in returning the ASC charact associated with an ASCII value.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Locates occurrences of targeted special characters found in the input string and replaces each with a space.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputString">The input string.</param>
    /// <returns>The updated inputString.</returns>
    private string ReplaceSpecialCharacters(string inputString)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(inputString);

        const string doubleQuoteCharacter = "\"";

        stringBuilder.Replace("\r\n", " "); // Carriage Return/Line Feed characters replaced with single space
        stringBuilder.Replace("\r", " "); // Carriage Return replaced with one space if only \r is found
        stringBuilder.Replace("\n", " "); // Likewise, Line Feed with a single space           
        stringBuilder.Replace(this.columnSeparator, " "); // Tab            
        stringBuilder.Replace(Character.GetCharacterString(150), Character.GetCharacterString(45)); // Replace Dash with Hypen
        stringBuilder.Replace(Character.GetCharacterString(147), doubleQuoteCharacter); // Replace angled left quote, “, with simple double quote, ".
        stringBuilder.Replace(Character.GetCharacterString(148), doubleQuoteCharacter); // Replace angled left quote, “, with simple double quote, ".

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Here are the conversion functions I found:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="Character.cs" company="Joes bar and grill">
// TODO: Update copyright text.
// </copyright>
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace JoesBarAndGrill.FinanceIT.HhsSweeper
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: Update summary.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Character
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// See http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/273734-c-chr-asc-function-equivalents-undocumented-truth.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="asciiValue"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetCharacterString(int asciiValue)
        {
            if ((asciiValue < 0) || (asciiValue > 255))
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("asciiValue", asciiValue, "Must be between 0 and 255.");
            }
            byte[] bytBuffer = new byte[] { (byte)asciiValue };
            return Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bytBuffer);
        }

        public static int GetAsciiValue(string character)
        {
            if (character.Length != 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("character", character, "Must be a single character.");
            }
            char[] chrBuffer = { Convert.ToChar(character) };
            byte[] bytBuffer = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(chrBuffer);
            return (int)bytBuffer[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Again, my question is this:

What do I have to do to come up with a general approach to identify all characters that may end up having conversion issues like this? I think I may have identified the common ones only. I would also be interested in having people help me come up with a more complete list of targetcharacters to replace and proposed substitution characters.

I am not sure if this is related, but in case someone suggests that I use a text delimiter in the CSV file, I am not using a text qualifier because I am convinced that SSIS 2008 does not handle them correctly (see [a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239530/using-excel-to-create-a-csv-file-with-special-characters-and-then-importing-it-i))

Comment: Prior to SSIS, we used the [Unicode Hammer](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/251871-latin1-to-ascii-the-unicode-hammer/) to smash all those "funny" characters into basic ascii values. I haven't given it any thought how best to handle it in the .NET era

Comment: For the sake of argument, it might be better to use a string builder where you are replacing and rebuilding that string multiple times.

Comment: @Nick, thanks. I have use StringBuilders for string concatenation operations and never noticed that there is a Replace function on the SB object. Thanks. Code updated.

Comment: This might not be an encoding isssue. MS-Word sometimes replaces "standard" characters by typographic ones. `"` by `„` or `“` for example.

Comment: So it sounds like you don't want to just simply remove non ASCII characters. You want to handle them on a case by case basis and attempt to replace them with an ASCII equivalent?

Comment: @Nick: I think that may be a good synopsis of my goal.

Comment: So you would probably need to use a switch statement and specify what ASCII character to replace it with.

Comment: Notepad has no issues with displaying the variations of the dash and quote characters that I have identified and their ASCII values are <=  255, I don't see why Excel converts them to funny characters. I don't understand enough about the different encodings used and it surprises me that Excel has "issues" with characters that Notepad can handle.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all your Script code. Edit the Connection object for your Flat File.  Change the Code page to 65001 (UTF-8).

Comment: After thinking about this, I decided that if a user opens up the CSV file using Excel for the purpose of tweaking the data, that they should be able to see meaningful characters. Changing the Code page would just change the way that the data is loaded.