# Differentiating between zero-length varchar and NULL values in a CSV file

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Consider the following 6-row sample CSV file

```
"Col1","Col2", "Col3", 
"Col1Row1","Col2Row1", 1
"Col1Row2","", 
"Col1Row3",,0
"Row 4 Example of ""double quotes"" in the data","Row 4 col 2",0
"Row 5 Example of a comma, no problem, in the data","Row 5 col 2",0
"Row 6 Example of embedded CR LF right here
 in the data","Row 6 col 2",0
```

## Properties of file:

1. Column Heading = True
2. Column delimiter char = comma
3. Text delimiter char = "
4. row delimiter = {CR}{LF}
5. Text Delimiter in data represented by two consecutive occurrences of the text delimiter char

## Column definitions:

1. Col1 = varchar
2. Col2 = varchar
3. Col3 = numeric

As I recall from my days using DTS, DTS Packages had no issues processing files that may contain a Column Delimiter, text delimiter or row delimiter character(s) in the data. furthermore, it could also distinguish between NULL and non null values and in particular NULL strings vs. zero-length strings.

After what I consider sufficient testing, I have commented in this Stack Overflow posting that I believe SSIS's CSV parser simply cannot handle special characters in the data, eg, Text Delimiter or Row Delimiter characters in the data. See [Using Excel to create a CSV file with special characters and then Importing it into a db using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239530/using-excel-to-create-a-csv-file-with-special-characters-and-then-importing-it-i). I still can't believe it and mention it again for hope that I am mistaken, since it seems unfathomable to me that SSIS cannot handle this case and that the only work-around is to select a Text Delimiter that does not occur in the data.

However, let me get to my primary question about NULL values. Recently, I discovered that unless I set the "Retain Null Values" property on the File Input object

[image]
and the "Keep Null values" property on the destination table object,

[image]

that the NULL values are not detected and the null value become zero length varchar values or 0, in the case of a numeric destination column. In my example above, I consider the following row columns to have null values:

1. Row 2 Col 3
2. Row 3, Col 2

Since my destination database is SQL Server which differentiates between a zero-length varchar and a null varchar, I do not consider the value in row 2 column 2 to be null, but instead, a zero-length varchar. However, when the data is transfered from theis sample file to a destination table that allows nulls for all of these columns, the zero-length strings are loaded as a NULL!

Since the "Retain NULLs" and "Keep Nulls" settings appear to be at the File and Table object level rather than at a column level, there seems to be no way to "turn on" "Retain Nulls" for just the column that I expect to have nulls. For example, let's say that I have a file with 42 varchar columns in it and for 41 one of them, I am content with having empty strings instead of nulls, but for a single column I would like to retain and differentiate between a NULL value and an empty string value, is there any way to do this? Both the null varchar columns and the zero-length varchar column values seem to be loaded as NULLS.

What is the best way to handle this, using a derived column transformation or a scripting task to modify the value? Could someone help me with the C# script or provide detail for either approach or suggest a better way?

I have seen some postings on SO saying that there is no way to differentiate between a NULL and zero-length varchar value in a CSV file, but I believe the above example is how you do it and that it is just a question of how you get the SSIS CSV parser to properly parse it or if the parser is up to snuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this doesn't entirely answer your question, but here's what I've found.

I haven't tested the Keep Nulls property on the OLEDB Destination, because I think that has a slightly different meaning.  I'm verifying all my tests by looking at Data Viewers within SSIS, cutting the OLEDB Destination out of the picture as a factor.

1. When importing a non-text-qualified file, with Retain Null Values unticked, both empty columns (i.e. two delimiters with nothing in between them), and columns containing only spaces are imported as-is: as a zero-length string, and a series of spaces respectively.
2. If you tick Retain Null Values, the zero-length column will be transformed to NULL, but the column containing spaces will remain as-is.
3. With a text-qualified file, it gets more complicated.  With Retain Null Values unticked, there's just no way to get a NULL from the file.  Whether it's a properly-qualified empty string (e.g. "","NextColumnValue"), or just nothing at all (i.e. ,"NextColumnValue"), SSIS turns it into a zero-length string.
4. With a text-qualified file, and Retain Null Values ticked, here's the results, both the properly-qualified empty string ("") and the complete lack of anything between the column delimiters are turned to NULL.

These results are consistent with what you've found.  And there definitely doesn't seem to be a column-by-column setting which can be adjusted: using the Retain Nulls checkbox, you can either turn all zero-length strings (and absences of text qualifiers, if applicable) into NULL, or you can leave them as zero-length strings.